# Background removal with hair

Tags: image-processing, image, background

I'd like RemoveBackgound to work on images where the foreground boundary is nontrivial e.g. with hair:

```
i=CloudGet@"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/9e4ccbbb-9f08-42b9-8602-1c868245b8b1";
RemoveBackground[i]
```

Like Pixelmator Pro does:

```
CloudGet@"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/4d591717-e566-4df3-bc67-969d89434c62"
```

[image]

**One Approach**

To get the subject, we could use a neural net, but the models on the wolfram repo don't have high enough fidelity or deal with alpha channels (which is really necessary). For example, here's what Ademxapp segmentation gives:

```
netevaluate[img_, device_ : "CPU"] := Block[
  {net, resized, encData, dec, mean, var, prob},
  net = NetModel["Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on ADE20K Data"];
  resized = ImageResize[img, {504}];
  encData = Normal@NetExtract[net, "Input"];
  dec = NetExtract[net, "Output"];
  {mean, var} = Lookup[encData, {"MeanImage", "VarianceImage"}];
  prob = NetReplacePart[net,
     {"Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", ImageDimensions@resized, "MeanImage" -> mean, "VarianceImage" -> var}], "Output" -> Automatic}
     ][resized, TargetDevice -> device];
  prob = ArrayResample[prob, Append[Reverse@ImageDimensions@img, 150]];
  dec[prob]
  ]
mask=netevaluate[i]
```

[image]

Comment: Try: "RemoveBackground[i, {"Background", {"Blurred", 2}}"] It is not great but maybe it is good enough.

Comment: Not good nuf. I'd like to get as close as the video of pixelmator shows.

Comment: Have you tried one of the neural nets, eg https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Ademxapp-Model-A1-Trained-on-ADE20K-Data/ - extract the correct label and remove the rest.

Comment: @CarlLange I did, those nets especially the older ones from before 2020 are terrible at thin or wispy segments.

Comment: @CarlLange See my edit

Comment: Seems MMA is not competitive

Comment: Just for your information : your code `CloudGet@"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/4d591717-e566-4df3-bc67-969d89434c62"` doesn"t work on my machine (Mma 12. 2 Windows 7). It returns an inert object `Video[...]`.